# rendering JSON (post request) into polymorphic type

Tags: grails

I want to deserialze a json from post request into the appropriate type.

- I Have domain class 
  A,B,C
  while B,C extends A

my code inside a controller :

```
class ReportController {
  def notification() {
     A notification = new A(request.JSON);
  }
}
```

- Yet ,My code only de-serialzes class A fields ,just as expected.
- Is there any way to register the sub-classes, to allow straight forward de-serialzation?
- I perform post request to notification() , Attaching class B or C JSON.
- I need to deserialze the json into B or C, Avoiding creation of custom input validator.

Comment: how would you detect from the submitted json, what type it should be mapped to?

Comment: it exists in Jackson, using either a class property ,or by elimination of different fields, though the second method is not deterministic